# SQL Alchemy - Logically delete models with specific status

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I am trying to logically delete some documents in my Database according to its status ('removed').
I have my DocumentStatus

```
class DocumentStatus(Base):
    __tablename__ = "DocumentStatus"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,unique=True)
    enumerator = Column(String)
    created_at = Column(DateTime
```

and my documents

```
class Document(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Document"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)

    operation_info_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(OperationInfoModel.id))

    document_status_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey(DocumentStatusModel.id), nullable=False
    )
    document_status = relationship(
        "DocumentStatus", foreign_keys=[document_status_id], lazy="joined"
    )
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
```

Finally I have some operations that contain these documents, and I would like to exclude all documents that have document_status.enumerator == 'removed'
Here is my Operation Model

```
class OperationInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "OperationInfo"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)

    operation_info_key = Column(String)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)

    attached_documents = relationship("AttachedDocument", lazy="selectin")
```

I was trying to do so through primaryjoin

```
primaryjoin="and_(OperationInfo.id == AttachedDocument.operation_info_id, AttachedDocument.document_status_id == DocumentStatus.id, DocumentStatus.enumerator!=\"removed\")"
```

but it does not work. Does anyone know how to solve my problem?